# I want to upgrade my mongodb from 3.2 to 4.2

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am currently using MongoDB 3.2 version and Spring Data version 1.4.3.

Now I want to update my MongoDB to 4.2. So which version of Spring Data, I must be using and which all version of Spring Data is compatible with MongoDB 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data MongoDB depends on the Java driver compatibility. Please have a look at the [MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#java-driver-compatibility) for the full matrix.

Spring Data release [Moore](https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/01/spring-data-moore-goes-ga) (aka version *2.2*) pulls in *3.11* which is the recommended driver for MongoDB Server *4.2*.

Please note that, due to several API changes between the 1.x and 2.x line of SpringData, this is no drop in replacement.